I encountered the problem of importing Media3
I was completely confused. I want to use the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exoplayer-in-android-with-example/ example on the web and install and use Exoplayer. I made a mistake at the very beginning.
my implementation is:
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.1")
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.3.1")
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.3.1")

when i "import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;" give the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'media3'" and color of media3 is red.
I was completely confused. what is the problem.

As far as I know, import is not necessary. Take a look to "Declaring dependencies": https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media3
